# Any layout/geometry management for Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa

If i create WinForms / Qt / Gtk application i use so called "layout managers" (or "geometry managers") to automatically layout my UI according to text inside widgets and my instructions. For example, if i layout a window with big edit field and 2 buttons below it aligned right i write following code "Create a window with vertical layout manager. Add edit widget as first item and horizontal layout manager as second item. For horizontal layout manager add spacer as first item, button as second and button as third". My window will be automatically resized according to button labels and edit field size. Also, if i resize my window all items will be resized automatically.

Is it something like layout managers for OSX? I have found that NSView can be added into hierarchy, but i can't find any ways to instruct parent NSView something like "arrange child NSViews vertically".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read about [Cocoa Auto Layout](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH1-SW1), new in OS X 10.7.

Comment: Am i correct that prior to 10.7 where was no layout / geomatry management? Absolute coords and manual resize of each item on window resize? O_O

Comment: No. [Autoresizing Masks](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH4-SW12) have been there since 10.0 but they are not as flexible. There is also the concept of [layout managers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006084-SW1) for Core Animation layers.

Comment: The link above is dead. I think this is what you wanted: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1

Answer (score -1):

Cocoa auto layout is very close to the layout managers we want. This video provides an excellent introduction: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mhvKKBha0fw