# How to chain NSView to simulate pagination?

Tags: cocoa, pagination, nsview, chain

I'd like to chain several views together and have content flow from one view to the next automatically. Think of how text containers work and how their content can span across containers. Does anyone have an idea how this might be done?

Comment: It would span subviews (NSViews) automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You could build something like this from scratch, with a layout manager which manages a set of container views.

This code is designed to vertically resize a container to hold its subviews:

```
+ (void)setAndArrangeSubviews:(NSArray *)subviews inView:(NSView *)superview {
    [superview setSubviews:subviews];

    NSRect superviewFrame = [superview frame];
    CGFloat y = superviewFrame.size.height;
    for (NSView *subview in subviews) {
        NSRect subviewFrame = [subview frame];
        subviewFrame.origin.y = (y -= subviewFrame.size.height);
        [subview setFrame:subviewFrame];
    }
}
```

You could adapt it to accomplish what you want: arranging subviews in the container until it's full, then arranging the remaining views in the next container.

If you only need to stack the views vertically, this seems an easy enough way to accomplish what you want.

The answer to this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227078/any-layout-geometry-management-for-cocoa) refers to a 10.7 feature called [Cocoa Auto Layout](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH1-SW1), which may provide a more automatic way to accomplish this, which might be worth investigating if you need to lay these out in 2D.